# How to disable maximize button in livecode

Tags: livecode

I am beginner in livecode, How to disable maximize button, This is my code

```
 get shell("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':close'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code

```
set the resizable stack "name of the stack" to false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "decorations" property to enable or disable window buttons. If you do it by script, the window will flicker as it redraws. If you only need to set it once permanently, you can do that using the stack's property inspector.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native keyword in LC, used in conjunction with the "decorations" property,  that handles this: "maximize".

You do not need a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

What Jacque said. Here is the code:

```
set the decorations of stack "myStack" to "close,minimize"
```

Comment: I'll need to know exactly what is or isn't happening to help you. Is there an error message? What does it say? Have you made sure everything is spelled correctly in your statement?